# Users that disliked my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is it possible to access stats about who and when disliked my page on Facebook? I looked through menu at Facebook, but I cannot find anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, now (2+ year later) with New Page Insights you can view at least some info about unlikes.

To access this data:

1. Go to the *New Page Insights* section, while being logged in to Facebook as your Page.
2. Click on *Page Likes* box title or navigate to **Likes** tab.
3. In third chart (*Net Likes: What Changed*) click on **Unlikes** below *Benchmark* in right box.

As description for this chart says, net likes are "pure" likes, that is *likes–unlikes*.